# Why can't socket return any data

Tags: python, sockets, networking

The page exists because I have a link to it:  http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt

Here's the code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode('utf-8')

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if(len(data)) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

I wanted the code to retrieve the data from the file on the web, decode it and then run a loop to print out each line of the text in the file along with the headers.

The code seems to be laid out correctly and there are no syntax errors. However, it always returns an empty output.

I have tried adding www. and removing it. I have tried using the terminal to run the page rather than VSC and that returned the same empty output.

Why doesn't the socket return any data?

Comment: As a side note, remember you will NOT receive each line of the text separately.  TCP is a streaming protocol, not line-oriented.  You'll get however much was sent, up to the size of your buffer.  Lines are not relevant.  In this particular case it doesn't matter, but later it might.

Answer (score 1):

1. Send the command.
2. HTTP protocol specifies `\r\n` for newlines, not only `\n`.

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode('utf-8')
mysock.sendall(cmd) # send the command and add          ^^  ^^

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if(len(data)) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Apr 2023 22:25:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 May 2017 11:22:22 GMT
ETag: "1d3-54f6609240717"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 467
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

Why should you learn to write programs?

Writing programs (or programming) is a very creative 
and rewarding activity.  You can write programs
 for 
many reasons, ranging from making your living to solving
a difficult data analysis problem to having fun to helping
someone else solve a problem.  This book assumes that 
everyone needs to know how to program, and that once 
you know how to program you will figure out what you want 
to do with your newfound skills.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode('utf-8')
```

to:

```
cmd = 'GET /intro-short.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```